# maven-antrun-plugin: generate sources for protobuf does not generate Java files

Tags: maven, protocol-buffers, maven-antrun-plugin

I have the following plugin in my `pom.xml`, which is supposed to generate java files required for the compilation of other projects:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${jdk.version}</source>
        <target>${jdk.version}</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestFile>META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <mkdir dir="src-gen" />
                    <exec executable="protoc">
                        <arg value="--java_out=src-gen" />
                        <arg value="proto/ros/RosTime.proto" />
                        <arg value="proto/ros/RosHeader.proto" />
                        <arg value="proto/ros/RosPoint.proto" />
                        <arg value="proto/ros/RosPose.proto" />
                        <arg value="proto/ros/RosPoseStamped.proto" />
                        <arg value="proto/ros/RosQuaternion.proto" />
                        <arg value="proto/U.proto" />
                        <arg value="proto/S.proto" />
                        <arg value="proto/Z.proto" />
                        <arg value="proto/algorithm/A.proto" />
                        <arg value="proto/algorithm/B.proto" />
                        <arg value="proto/algorithm/C.proto" />
                        <arg value="proto/algorithm/D.proto" />
                        <arg value="proto/algorithm/E.proto" />
                        <arg value="proto/algorithm/F.proto" />
                        <arg value="proto/env/G.proto" />
                        <arg value="proto/env/H.proto" />
                        <arg value="proto/env/J.proto" />
                        <arg value="proto/env/K.proto" />
                        <arg value="proto/env/L.proto" />
                    </exec>
                </tasks>
                <sourceRoot>src-gen</sourceRoot>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

However, this does not generate anything at all, under src-gen folder. And then I keep getting errors such as :

```
    cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class AMsg
[ERROR] location: class project.messages.AFormatter
```

and

```
package project.messages.ros.RosHeader does not exist
package project.messages.ros.RosPoint does not exist
package project.messages.ros.RosPose does not exist
package project.messages.ros.RosPoseStamped does not
```

basically it cannot find the necessary files, naturally, and gives error. I have the 2.5.0 version installed already, and the dependency is defined correctly:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I've ran out of ideas. What is really making this not working?

**EDIT:** The following took my attention in the debug output of `mvn install -X` :

```
Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'protoc' with arguments:

'--java_out=src-gen'
'proto/ros/RosTime.proto'
'proto/ros/RosHeader.proto'
'proto/ros/RosPoint.proto'
'proto/ros/RosPose.proto'
'proto/ros/RosPoseStamped.proto'
'proto/ros/RosQuaternion.proto'
 .
 .
 .
 . 
The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command.
     [exec] ros/RosTime.proto: File not found.
     [exec] proto/ros/RosHeader.proto: Import "ros/RosTime.proto" was not found or had errors.
     [exec] proto/ros/RosHeader.proto:6:14: "project.messages.ros.RosTimeMsg" seems to be defined in "proto/ros/RosTime.proto", which is not imported by "proto/ros/RosHeader.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
  .
  .  
  .
     [INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (generate-sources) @ X.messages ---
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9:compile
[DEBUG]          junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile
[DEBUG]          classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.7.1:runtime
[DEBUG]    org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.7.1:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < project>runtime_shared:art.util.robot:1.0.0
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.7.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.7.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.4
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.4
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.4
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.4
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.4
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.4
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.4
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.4
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run' with override configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) pluginArtifacts = [org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:maven-plugin:1.3:, junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.6:compile, org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.7.1:runtime, org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.7.1:compile]
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: runtime_X:X.messages:1.0.0 @ /home/usr/workspace_runtime_X/X.messages/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) sourceRoot = /home/usr/workspace_runtime_X/X.messages/src-gen
[DEBUG]   (f) tasks = 
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
```

Comment: Are you saying that the `maven-antrun-plugin` isn't invoked at all? Or it is invoked but `protoc` isn't getting called or isn't generating the files? Can you post the logs relating to `maven-antrun-plugin` when ran with `-X`?

Comment: It is invoked, I can see `[exec] Executing 'protoc' with arguments: [exec] '--java_out=src-gen'` and such lines in the debug output. Let me share the relevant stuff under the question. EDIT: just added the debug output.

Comment: Can you try with `--java_out=${basedir}/src-gen` (i.e. specify an absolute path)?

Comment: No luck unfortunately. Could you recommend another way of dealing with protocol buffers (a way that does not involve Ant, possibly)? A plugin which is easy to use in this regard, for instance.

Comment: BTW that was giving me this error: `[exec] /home/usr/workspace_runtime_x/x.messages/proto/ros/RosTime.proto: File does not reside within any path specified using --proto_path (or -I).  You must specify a --proto_path which encompasses this file.  Note that the proto_path must be an exact prefix of the .proto file names -- protoc is too dumb to figure out when two paths (e.g. absolute and relative) are equivalent (it's harder than you think).`

Comment: I honestly don't know about other ways to do this. But the error message sounds like you're missing a `--proto_path` parameter. Maybe you need to add something like `<arg value="--proto_path=${basedir}" />` (assuming all those `proto/....proto` are in the base dir).

Comment: I've managed to generate the java files now but it still gives the error. I think it does not compile them and does not generate the necessary .class files

Comment: Ah that is possible. `<sourceRoot>` is deprecated. You should use the build-helper-maven-plugin to add a source folder: see http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html

Comment: That did the magic indeed. Damn, spent too much time in this. Can't thank you enough. I can accept your contribution if you write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt about files not getting created, make sure you use absolute path. In this case, `${basedir}` allows us to get the absolute path to the location of the Maven base directory (location of POM):

```
<mkdir dir="${basedir}/src-gen" />
<exec executable="protoc">
    <arg value="--java_out=${basedir}/src-gen" />
    <arg value="--proto_path=${basedir}" /> <!-- proto_path needs to point to where the proto files are -->
    <arg value="proto/ros/RosTime.proto" />
    <!-- rest of proto files... -->
</exec>
```

Then, note that the [`<sourceRoot>`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/run-mojo.html#sourceRoot) parameter of the `maven-antrun-plugin` is deprecated:

> Deprecated. Use the build-helper-maven-plugin to bind source directories

As recommended, you should use the [`build-helper-maven-plugin:add-source`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-source-mojo.html) goal to add a source folder to your Maven project. Configure the folders to add with the [`sources`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-source-mojo.html#sources) parameter of that goal.

---

Having said that, you might have better chance using the [`org.xolstice.maven.plugins:protobuf-maven-plugin`](https://www.xolstice.org/protobuf-maven-plugin/) instead of relying on Ant tasks:

> Maven Protocol Buffers Plugin uses Protocol Buffer Compiler (`protoc`) tool to generate Java source files from `.proto` (protocol buffer definition) files for the specified project.

The [`compile`](https://www.xolstice.org/protobuf-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html) goal can be used to generate the Java source files. Placing your `.proto` files under `src/main/proto` (configurable with the [`protoSourceRoot`](https://www.xolstice.org/protobuf-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#protoSourceRoot) parameter), the plugin will generate the Java source files inside `${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/protobuf/java` (configurable with the [`outputDirectory`](https://www.xolstice.org/protobuf-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#outputDirectory) parameter).

In case the `protoc` executable isn't in the PATH environment variable, you can set it with the [`protocExecutable`](https://www.xolstice.org/protobuf-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#protocExecutable) parameter.