# How to make/turn ".proto" files into ".java" using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, protocol-buffers

So I've installed protobufs using Maven but I just can't wrap my head around the readmes. What I would like to get is a step-by-step guide telling me how to:

1. Make a .proto file
2. How to edit said .proto file(no problem w/ coding just no idea how to create/edit one)
3. How to turn the .proto into a .java
   Thanks in advance and sorry for being a doofus :P

Comment: A readme would be too broad for Stack Overflow, but you can possibly refer to this answer of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746245/maven-antrun-plugin-generate-sources-for-protobuf-does-not-generate-java-files/38763459#38763459

Comment: What about the Maven Protobuf plugin? https://www.xolstice.org/protobuf-maven-plugin/